# Proving primes in Coq

Tags: primes, coq

I have a Coq function that **classifies prime numbers**.
I exported it to Haskell and tested it; it works fine.
I want to rigorously prove it indeed classifies primes,
so I tried to prove the following theorem `isPrimeCorrect`:

```
(************)
(* helper'' *)
(************)
Fixpoint helper' (p m n : nat) : bool :=
  match m with
  | 0 => false
  | 1 => false
  | S m' => (orb ((mult m n) =? p) (helper' p m' n))
  end.

(**********)
(* helper *)
(**********)
Fixpoint helper (p m : nat) : bool :=
  match m with
  | 0 => false
  | S m' => (orb ((mult m m) =? p) (orb (helper' p m' m) (helper p m')))
  end.

(***********)
(* isPrime *)
(***********)
Fixpoint isPrime (p : nat) : bool :=
  match p with
  | 0 => false
  | 1 => false
  | S p' => (negb (helper p p'))
  end.

(***********)
(* divides *)
(***********)
Definition divides (n p : nat) : Prop :=
  exists (m : nat), ((mult m n) = p).

(*********)
(* prime *)
(*********)
Definition prime (p : nat) : Prop :=
  (p > 1) /\ (forall (n : nat), ((divides n p) -> ((n = 1) \/ (n = p)))).

(*****************************)
(* isPrime correctness proof *)
(*****************************)
Theorem isPrimeCorrect: forall (p : nat),
  ((isPrime p) = true) <-> (prime p).
```

I spent a good few hours on this theorem today with no actual progress.
Actually, I was a bit surprised how difficult it is since I previously 
managed to prove pretty similar stuff. Any hints/clues how to proceed?

Comment: A few remarks : `isPrime` does not need to be declared as a `Fixpoint`; some of your definitions exist in the standard library (`Nat.divide`, `ZArith.Znumtheory.prime`). But maybe you want to experiment with your own definitions.

Comment: @eponier yes, I want to use the above definitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must explicitely write lemmas for each of the helping functions, which state exactly what you think this function does for you.  For instance, I tried to do this for your `helper'` function and I came up with the following lemma:

```
Require Import Arith Psatz.

(************)
(* helper'' *)
(************)
Fixpoint helper' (p m n : nat) : bool :=
  match m with
  | 0 => false
  | 1 => false
  | S m' => (orb ((mult m n) =? p) (helper' p m' n))
  end.


Lemma helper'_correct :
  forall p m n,
    helper' p m n = true <-> exists k, (1 < k <= m /\ p = k * n).
Proof.
intros p; induction m as [ | m' IH]; intros n.
  split;[discriminate | ].
  intros [k [abs _]].
  lia.  (* Here the hypothesis abs has statement  1 <= k < 0 
            and lia recognizes that it is absurd. *)
destruct m' as [ | m''] eqn: E.
  split;[discriminate | intros [k [abs _]]; lia].
change (helper' p (S (S m'')) n) with (orb ((mult (S (S m'')) n) =? p)
                                    (helper' p (S m'') n)).
rewrite Bool.orb_true_iff.
split.
  intros [it | later].
    now exists (S (S m'')); split;[lia | symmetry; apply beq_nat_true ].
  rewrite IH in later; destruct later as [k [k1 k2]].
  exists k.
  (* here hypothesis k1 states 1 < k <= S m''
                     k2 states p = k * n
     and we need to prove 1 < k <= S (S m'') /\ p = k * n
     lia can do that automatically. *)
  lia.
intros [k [[k1 km] k2]].
apply le_lt_or_eq in km; rewrite or_comm in km; destruct km as [km | km].
  now left; rewrite <- km; rewrite Nat.eqb_eq, k2.
right; apply lt_n_Sm_le in km.
change (helper' p (S m'') n = true); rewrite IH.
exists k.
lia.
Qed.
```

Obviously there should also be a way to link the `helper` function wih the `divides` predicate.

Comment: Could you give an example of using the `lia` tactic? Also, is proving that `k <=m` in the `->` direction straightforward?

Comment: I changed the answer to include the full proof of the first lemma.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I seem to be stuck with `rewrite IH in later;` saying: `Error:
Found no subterm matching "helper' p (S m'') ?n = true" in the current goal.`

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, I made several trials while writing the answer, and then I did not clean the script correctly.  I checked this one with coqc (8.9).

Comment: Thanks a lot, that works. I learned a lot from this worked solution, and I hope others can benefit from it too.

Comment: If you need to see it, I have a complete proof of your target theorem at your disposal, but stack-overflow is not the right place for it.  Answer to this message if you want to have access, I'll arrange something.

Comment: I would very much like to see the whole proof. Thanks.

Comment: look [here](https://www-sop.inria.fr/members/Yves.Bertot/proofs/OrenIshShalom_primes.v)